# How to check whether JavaScript debugging is enabled or not in react-native android

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to perform some actions in react-native android's native side based on whether JavaScript debugging is enabled or not.

So, How to find that whether debugging is enable or not in native side?

Answer (score 0):

In android emulator you need to run ctl + m and on actual device just need to shake the device. Better check this documentation [Debugging](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html)

Comment: Yes ..that i know, but I am trying to find the debug status in native code. I am looking for some object which tells whether debugging is enabled or not which i can access in my native file and do my things .Earlier in react-native v0.27.0, it used to be exposed in reactBridge object via executors but now in latest version it is moved elsewhere which i cant access.